# MIDI Note Message in C++

Tags: c++, audio, midi, libsndfile

I'm trying to make a piece of software using C++ that plays a .wav audio sample when a certain MIDI key is pressed. The best way I thought about doing this is using an `if` statement (if there's an easier way I would much appreciate it, but I'm quite the novice to programming so please keep it simple).

Having looked online, I've found out that different MIDI keys correspond to different NOTE ON messages (for example, NOTE ON 60 would correspond to middle C), so basically I'm just looking for how to say "when NOTE ON 60 is received, play X .wav file". I've also found out that the status for NOTE ON is `9n`, so would this mean the computer would receive `9x60` (using the 60 = Middle C example)?

After this I would just need to find out how to play an audio sample, which I believe would be the following, using `sndfile.h`:

```
SNDFILE *sndFile = sf_open("Sample1.wav").
```

Any help would be very greatly appreciated.

Comment: The problem here is that your English is slightly off. In fact what you mean to say is _"**when** NOTE ON 60 is received, play X .wave file"_ and "when" differs hugely from "if", at least in C++ programming. As such, this is something of a broad question.

Comment: Ah okay, I'll edit that now.

Answer (score 0):

you can use
[PortAudio](http://portaudio.com/)
it has everything that you can work with midi and your wave files

Comment: Ah great! And how would I code "when NOTE ON 60 is received, play X .wav file" with PortAudio? Thanks very much for your reply by the way!

Answer (score 0):

you can implement a stream function with portAudio and check with portMidi that when note c4 for example is pressed, play that file
look at there documentation